# Need to convert a simple number set to text with if, then, else in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

Fairly new to Crystal Reports. Need to convert numbers to text in a formula. This is what I've tried, along with several others, but returns an error. Any suggestions helpful!

```
IF {Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 1 then totext "Open" 
or if 2 = then totext = "Closed-Sale"
or if 3 = then totext = "Closed-Expired"
or if 4 = then totext = "Closed-No Interest"
or if 5 = then totext = "Closed-Extended"
or if 6 = then totext = "Closed-Sale(Auto)"
or if 7 = then totext = "Closed-Future Interest"
or if 8 = then totext = "Closed Not Qualified"
else totext is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a CASE-statement for this.

```
select {Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID}
 case 1 : "Open"  
 case 2 : "Closed-Sale"
 case 3 : "Closed-Expired"
 case 4 : "Closed-No Interest"
.
.
.
default : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this inside the actual Crystal Report, you need to use the Switch statement.

```
Switch ({Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 1, "Open",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 2, "Closed-Sale",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 3, "Closed-Expired",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 4, "Closed-No Interest",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 5, "Closed-Extended",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 6, "Closed-Sale(Auto)",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 7, "Closed-Future Interest",
{Ref_Referrals.ReferralStatusID} = 8, "Closed Not Qualified",
True, "")
```

The last line of the Switch returns a 0-length string if none of the previous 8 conditions are true.

Edit: If for some reason you still really want to do this with IF THEN ELSE, you would need to use nested ELSE IFs. The SWITCH is designed to replace nested ELSE IF, though. Just a thought.

Comment: I like the Switch (mostly because I understood it better). When I checked the formula, it returned an error message of "A number, currency, amount, boolean, date, time, date-time or string is expected here." after the "Open" ,   Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Crystal are you using? The above example comes from CR XI.